# if a global or static C variable is not explicitly initialized, but implicitly initialized, is it in .data or .bss section?

Tags: elf

Computer Systems: A Programmer's Perspective says about two sections in a ELF relocatable object file:

> - **.data** Initialized global and static C variables. Local C variables are maintained at run time on the stack and do not appear in
>     either the .data or .bss sections.
> - **.bss** Uninitialized global and static C variables, along with any global or static variables that are initialized to zero. This section
>     occupies no actual space in the object ﬁle; it is merely a
>     placeholder. Object ﬁle formats distinguish between initialized and
>     uninitialized variables for space efﬁciency: unini- tialized variables
>     do not have to occupy any actual disk space in the object ﬁle. At run
>     time, these variables are allocated in memory with an initial value of
>     zero.

Do "initialized" and "unitiailized" in the quote mean explicitly or implicitly or either?

if a global or static C variable is not explicitly initialized, but implicitly initialized, is it in .data or .bss section?

Does it matter whether the global or static C variable is  implicitly initialized to zero or nonzero?

The requirements for .data and for .bss are not mutually exclusive. 
The .data requirement of "Initialized global and static C variables" doesn't say that such variables must be initialized to nonzero. So if a global or static C variable is initialized to zero, should it be in .data or .bss section?

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you write a small C program, and test what happens?

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's "implicitly" or "explicitly" initialized -- If it starts out as 0, it's in the `bss`.

Comment: @mosvy .data is only for Initialized global and static C variables initialized to nonzero?

Comment: that's the way it is by default. but you can force a variable into the `.data` section with eg. `int var __attribute((section (".data")));`.

Comment: What, is this off topic?

Comment: wouldn't it depend somewhat on the compiler?   anyway, you may get a better answer on stackoverflow.com, than on unix.stackexchange.com.  There's a larger body of developers there (or so it seems to me).

Answer (score 2):

> Do "initialized" and "unitiailized" in the quote mean explicitly or implicitly or either?

“Initialised” means that the variable is given an explicit value (which might be zero) alongside its declaration in the code. “Uninitialised” means that the variable isn’t explicitly initialised at declaration time, which in your terminology corresponds to “implicitly initialised”; if it’s a global variable, its value is zero.

> If a global or static C variable is not explicitly initialized, but implicitly initialized, is it in .data or .bss section?

As per your quote:

> **.bss** Uninitialized global and static C variables

Next:

> Does it matter whether the global or static C variable is implicitly initialized to zero or nonzero?

Uninitialised global variables are zero-valued by default.

> So if a global or static C variable is initialized to zero, should it be in .data or .bss section?

As per your quote:

> **.bss** Uninitialized global and static C variables, along with any global or static variables that are initialized to zero.

Note that none of this is a *requirement*; in particular, it assumes that uninitialised data segments are initialised to values corresponding to zero in C on the platform. This is typically the case on systems using ELF, but C allows zero to be represented by a bit pattern other than all zeroes.

In practice however, global or static variables initialised to zero, explicitly or not, are part of `.bss` in ELF binaries.

Comment: Thanks. Is .data  only for Initialized global and static C variables initialized to nonzero?

Comment: Yes, your quote itself says “any global or static variables that are initialized to zero” go in `.bss`, not `.data`. See [the Wikipedia page on `.bss`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.bss) for more background.